# HTML Input and Button not resizing proportionally

Tags: html, css, input, alignment, resizable

I'm trying to test HTML inputs and CSS units. What I have is a text input "merged" with a button. I'm trying to make the submit button and input stay proportional as the page resizes. Meaning, when I resize the page, the height and width should not stay the same and should shrink proportionally. I'm using the CSS unit "vw". 
The problem is, when I set the height and width to "(any number)vw" for them, **only the input** resizes the right way. The button just **stays the same size** no matter how I resize the page.

```css
loginText {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', bold;
  height: 4vw;
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', bold;
  font-size: '50px';
  height: 4.5vw;
  width: 6vw;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

loginText,
button {
  padding: 0.3em 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

loginText {
  height: 4vw;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

button:active,
button:hover {
  background-color: #acf;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginInputs" ; style="text-align: center; padding-top: 4%;">
  <form>
    <input id="loginText" name="something" type="text"><button>Go</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few things mistaken, like the padding on the button, wich prevented it from getting smaller at some point, also the `logintext` had no `#` infront of it.
it should work now :)

```css
#loginText {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 4vw;
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 4.5vw;
  width: 6vw;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#loginText,
button {
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#loginText {
  height: 4vw;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

button:active,
button:hover {
  background-color: #acf;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginInputs" ; style="text-align: center; padding-top: 4%;">
  <form>
    <input id="loginText" name="something" type="text"><button>Go</button>
  </form>
</div>
```